# End point not found in WCF Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, rest

When i test my WCFservice's method by putting as query string in address bar it shows only "Endpoint not found.".Please help me where i am wrong? But a simple test method to add two numbers is running properly.I am running it on localhost.Below is my web.config

```
 <connectionStrings>



    <add name="ES_SecurityContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=dev_Scheduler;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" executionTimeout="1599999" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

    <membership defaultProvider="simple">
      <providers>
        <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>

  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>


    <services>
      <!--<service name="Cygnus.Dev.JobDispatcherWCFService.JobDispatcherWcf">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="web" contract="Cygnus.Dev.JobDispatcherWCFService.IJobDispatcherWcf"></endpoint>


      </service>-->

      <service name="SchedulerWcf.Scheduler" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <!--<host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress=""/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>-->

        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SchedulerWcf.IScheduler" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="SchedulerWcf.IScheduler" />


      </service>


    </services>


    <behaviors>

      <!--<endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>-->

      <serviceBehaviors>


        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>


        <behavior>

          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>


      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>


    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>






</configuration>
```

below is the code of WCF Service

```
 public class Scheduler : IScheduler
    {

         #region [Constructors]
        public Scheduler()
        {
            if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ES_SecurityContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        }
        #endregion

        #region [Ping Test Methods]
        public string GetSum(int x, int y)
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { sum = x + y, message = "This is sum" });
        }
        #endregion
        #region [Methods]
        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
```

Comment: Reason for down voting ?

Comment: Hello, Could we please see you AppConfig file? Also, how is the service hosted?

Comment: Please post on how your SchedulerWcf.IScheduler interface looks?